# How to know, when did my app focused or unfocused- react native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I am developing a react-native app.

In one of the screens, there is a button, clicking on which, an email is sent to the user and the default email app is opened.

Now, the email contains a link, clicking on which, the user comes back to my app.

How can I know that the user has come back to my app from the email app?

React life-cycle methods like:

`componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`

are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the current state of the app. Then you can solve it using `AppState`.

`AppState` can tell you if the app is in the foreground or background, and notify you when the state changes.

`AppState` is frequently used to determine the intent and proper behavior when handling push notifications.

**Example**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native';

class AppStateExample extends Component {
  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === 'active'
    ) {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!');
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  };

  render() {
    return <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using AppState API: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.

> AppState can tell you if the app is in the foreground or background, and notify you when the state changes.
>
> **active** - The app is running in the foreground.
>
> **background** - The app is running in the background.
>
> **[iOS] inactive** - This is a state that occurs when transitioning between foreground & background, and during periods of inactivity such as entering the Multitasking view or in the event of an incoming call.

I have used it for resuming and stopping background music in an app.

This is link to official Apple Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle